# Update Multiple Sub Doc By array of sub doc _id's in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update multiple sub documents by given array of sub documents id's. I tried multiple approaches but it's not working.
In my scenario i need to update multiple sub documents by given array of id's. Here is my query as below:

**Approach 1.** (No elements were updating)

```
var updated = await ModelName.update(
                {
                    'subDocArray._id' : {  $in: req.body.elementId  } 
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        'subDocArray.$[elem].abc': req.body.abcValue,
                        'subDocArray.$[elem].xyz': req.body.xyzValue
                    },
                },{ "arrayFilters": [{ "elem._id":  {  $in: req.body.elementId  }  }], "multi": true, "upsert": true }
            ).lean().exec();
```

**Approach 2:** (Only First occurred element is updating)

```
var updated = await ModelName.update(
                {
                    'subDocArray._id' : {  $in: req.body.elementId  } 
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        'subDocArray.$.abc': req.body.abcValue,
                        'subDocArray.$.xyz': req.body.xyzValue
                    },
                },{ multi: true}
            ).exec();
```

Here `req.body.elementId` is array of sub doc id's.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1** was almost right. I was passing array of elementId's are which are in string format so i converted them in ObjectId form and then it works.

```
var arrOfObjectId = [];
req.body.elementId.forEach(elem => {
    arrOfObjectId.push(Types.ObjectId(elem))
});
```

To find the difference between both of the array i printed both in console which were showing like below:

console.log(req.body.elementId)
**Result:** ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'] //WRONG

console.log(arrOfObjectId)
**Result:** [ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),ObjectId('yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')]    //RIGHT

```
var updated = await ModelName.update(
                {
                    'subDocArray._id' : {  $in: arrOfObjectId  } 
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        'subDocArray.$[elem].abc': req.body.abcValue,
                        'subDocArray.$[elem].xyz': req.body.xyzValue
                    },
                },{ "arrayFilters": [{ "elem._id":  {  $in: arrOfObjectId  }  }], "multi": true, "upsert": true }
            ).lean().exec();
```